# How to re-order Intent response messages or auto chain Intents in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using Dialogflow and have x amount of Intents setup in a particular structure including both contextless intents & follow-up intents.

With this I have 1 default "Welcome Intent" that has a simple Text Response. However I also have a Google Assistance Response "Basic Card" type that I wish to be emitted before the default text response and was wondering if this is possible?

Alternatively I would like to be able to chain Intents in a way that it doesn't require user input before triggering the next Intent. I have seen [Triggering next intent without user input in Dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450064) referring to the API or Webhooks, although that seems to either require "Cloud Functions" enabled or for Webhooks specifying an endpoint on an application outside of Dialogflow. I would preferably have this logic contained within Dialogflow, so rather not with Webhooks. Via the API it's not immediately clear to me how to approach this so any guidance on this would be helpful.

I am also aware of similar questions raised on this, pointing out that Intents are based on user input / intentions, but regardless of this design I am still wondering if it were possible within the constraints outlined above?

Comment: So just to be sure, you have a welcome intent, this intent has 1 generic welcome message and if a user talks to your bot via Google Assistant, it should change the welcome message to include another message before the generic welcome. It should only do this for Google Assistant and without any usage of code, right?

Comment: I have added some more details, but open for code solutions, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do this just for the Assistant? Or for other chatbot clients that work with Dialogflow as well?

Comment: Yes for a chatbot with Kommunicate.io

Comment: You mentioned a "Google Assistant Response", so I was confused. And what can be done is highly dependent on what the client is going to be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313033/trigger-one-intent-at-the-end-of-another/59748134#59748134

This will help you.